# Optimizing MySQL query around elapsed time

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a database doing a hackernews/reddit-esque approach to ranking.

I have a database of posts with the following columns (the time column could be INT or TIMESTAMP, whichever proves more performant).

```
id: INT
points: INT
time: TIMESTAMP/INT
```

I want to order by "score", where score is calculated like this:

`Score = (P-1) / (T+2)^G`

where,
P = points of an item
T = time since submission (in hours)
G = Gravity, a constant (let's say 1.8)

So I compose a SQL query:

`SELECT * FROM post ORDER BY (points - 1) / POW(((TIMESTAMPDIFF(HOURS, NOW(), time) + 2, 1.8)`

Great, this works, but it's super slow because any indexes I might put will be ignored, since the values they index are part of a calculation.

I can put the `points - 1` part of the query in a generated column, but I can't see a way to finagle the elapsed time component into something that's indexable. Am I just out of luck here?

Comment: You can't.  There may be other approaches where you can eliminate lower scores -- say those with few points and long ago -- and just run on more recent data.

Comment: The sorting expression is highly volatile (sorting changes rapidly when time passes). You can't add an index on an expression that is changing second by second. Plus, you don't have a filtering condition: that means you are retrieving the whole table every time.

Comment: That's what I figured. In practice, I do cut out a bit with a where clause. Thanks.